# How to make a caption (via \captionof and extra margins) adhere to minipage margins?

Tags: captions, margins, minipage

I made use of the [caption-package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) to define a custom layout of the captions. Their width is set to `0.8\columnwidth`. As far as I understood the problem, this measure is not used when the caption is set in a minipage environment.

I'd like the captions be treated accordingly to their defined width when they are in a minipage evironment. How can I achieve that?

The catch is, it works without the extra definitions by the caption-package, but then the caption is just the vanilla ragged left style which I don't like that much.

**Picture of the Status Quo**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
tikz,
relsize,
amsmath,
booktabs,
tikz
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\usepackage[
labelfont=sf,
%labelfont=sc, %Kapitälchen, passt nicht wg. nicht-osf Ziffern
%%%%labelfont=it, %italics, 
%%%labelfont=sl, %slanted,
hypcap=false,
format=hang,
%margin={2cm,2cm}
width=0.8\columnwidth
]{caption}

\usetikzlibrary{
calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,
decorations.pathreplacing,
decorations.pathmorphing,
decorations.shapes,
decorations.text,
shapes,
shapes.geometric,
shapes.symbols,
matrix,
patterns,
intersections,
fit}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
>=latex
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[btc]
%\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.48\columnwidth}
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Dataset for Something  with an Arbitrary Caption to Highlight the Problem}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
\toprule
Store & A & B & C & D & E \\
\cmidrule(r{0.125em}){1-1}%
\cmidrule(lr{0.125em}){2-2}%
\cmidrule(lr{0.125em}){3-3}%
\cmidrule(lr{0.125em}){4-4}%
\cmidrule(lr{0.125em}){5-5}%
\cmidrule(l{0.25em}){6-6}%
Input & 0.75 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 5\\
Output & 0.5 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 5\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.48\columnwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
%
\draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (6,6);
%
\draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (6.5,0) node[midway,below=8pt]{Output}; %X-Achse
\draw[->,thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6.5) node[above=5pt]{Input}; %Y-Achse
%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](\x cm,-2pt) -- (\x cm,2pt);
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y);
%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw (\x cm, 0 cm) node[anchor=north]{\x} coordinate (x axis);
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,6}  \draw (0 cm, \y cm) node[anchor=east]{\y} coordinate (y axis);
%
\draw
(0,0) coordinate (orig)
(0.75,0.5) coordinate (A)
(1,2) coordinate (B)
(2,4) coordinate (C)
(5,2) coordinate (D)
(5,5) coordinate (E)
;
%
\foreach \pt/\labpos in {A/right,D/below left,E/below}{
  \fill (\pt) circle (2pt) node[\labpos=3pt,fill=white]{\pt};
};
\foreach \pt/\labpos in {B/above left,C/above left}{
  \fill (\pt) circle (3pt) node[\labpos=3pt,fill=white]{\pt};
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Graphical Illustration of Dataset with an Arbitrary Caption to Highlight the Problem}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `\columnwidth` for any of this but rather `\textwidth`. As for the caption with `\linewidth` seems more appropriate as `minipage` will set this. But it does not seem to work. Looks like `width=0.8\linewidth` just takes the current value at that time to be the with, it does not readjust it from time to time. A simple experiment confirms this to be true.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. They don't get readjusted, but another nested minipage or another environment would work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Update* third solution added using undocumented option `calcwidth` of `caption` mentioned in comment by the package author.

Two solutions

## First solution

If you need to keep you current width setting for captions in the rest of the text then
you can issue a new `\captionsetup` command just before each `\captionof` command.  Note that this is not as bad is it sounds as you can say

```
\captionsetup{width=0.8\linewidth}
```

in each of your cases.  The point is that the value of the line width its determined by the current `minipage` so this gives you `0.8` of the width of the current `minipage` environment:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
tikz,
relsize,
amsmath,
booktabs,
tikz
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\usepackage[
labelfont=sf,
hypcap=false,
format=hang,
width=0.8\columnwidth
]{caption}

\usetikzlibrary{
calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,
decorations.pathreplacing,
decorations.pathmorphing,
decorations.shapes,
decorations.text,
shapes,
shapes.geometric,
shapes.symbols,
matrix,
patterns,
intersections,
fit}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
>=latex
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[btc]
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\captionsetup{width=0.8\linewidth}
\captionof{table}{Dataset for Something  with an Arbitrary Caption to
Highlight the Problem}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
\toprule
Store & A & B & C & D & E \\
\cmidrule(r{0.125em}){1-1}%
\cmidrule(lr{0.125em}){2-2}%
\cmidrule(lr{0.125em}){3-3}%
\cmidrule(lr{0.125em}){4-4}%
\cmidrule(lr{0.125em}){5-5}%
\cmidrule(l{0.25em}){6-6}%
Input & 0.75 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 5\\
Output & 0.5 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 5\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
%
\draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (6,6);
%
\draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (6.5,0) node[midway,below=8pt]{Output}; %X-Achse
\draw[->,thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6.5) node[above=5pt]{Input}; %Y-Achse
%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](\x cm,-2pt) -- (\x cm,2pt);
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y);
%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw (\x cm, 0 cm) node[anchor=north]{\x} coordinate (x axis);
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,6}  \draw (0 cm, \y cm) node[anchor=east]{\y} coordinate (y axis);
%
\draw
(0,0) coordinate (orig)
(0.75,0.5) coordinate (A)
(1,2) coordinate (B)
(2,4) coordinate (C)
(5,2) coordinate (D)
(5,5) coordinate (E)
;
%
\foreach \pt/\labpos in {A/right,D/below left,E/below}{
  \fill (\pt) circle (2pt) node[\labpos=3pt,fill=white]{\pt};
};
\foreach \pt/\labpos in {B/above left,C/above left}{
  \fill (\pt) circle (3pt) node[\labpos=3pt,fill=white]{\pt};
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionsetup{width=0.8\linewidth}
\captionof{figure}{Graphical Illustration of Dataset with an Arbitrary Caption to Highlight the Problem}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

## Second solution

An alternative is to specify the caption structure via margin size rather than width, then you do not need to issue separate set-up commands each time:

[image: Sample margin specification]

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
tikz,
relsize,
amsmath,
booktabs,
tikz
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\usepackage[
labelfont=sf,
hypcap=false,
format=hang,
margin=1cm,
]{caption}

\usetikzlibrary{
calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,
decorations.pathreplacing,
decorations.pathmorphing,
decorations.shapes,
decorations.text,
shapes,
shapes.geometric,
shapes.symbols,
matrix,
patterns,
intersections,
fit}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
>=latex
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[btc]
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{center}
%\captionsetup{width=0.8\linewidth}
\captionof{table}{Dataset for Something  with an Arbitrary Caption to
Highlight the Problem}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
\toprule
Store & A & B & C & D & E \\
\cmidrule(r{0.125em}){1-1}%
\cmidrule(lr{0.125em}){2-2}%
\cmidrule(lr{0.125em}){3-3}%
\cmidrule(lr{0.125em}){4-4}%
\cmidrule(lr{0.125em}){5-5}%
\cmidrule(l{0.25em}){6-6}%
Input & 0.75 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 5\\
Output & 0.5 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 5\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
%
\draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (6,6);
%
\draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (6.5,0) node[midway,below=8pt]{Output}; %X-Achse
\draw[->,thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6.5) node[above=5pt]{Input}; %Y-Achse
%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](\x cm,-2pt) -- (\x cm,2pt);
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y);
%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw (\x cm, 0 cm) node[anchor=north]{\x} coordinate (x axis);
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,6}  \draw (0 cm, \y cm) node[anchor=east]{\y} coordinate (y axis);
%
\draw
(0,0) coordinate (orig)
(0.75,0.5) coordinate (A)
(1,2) coordinate (B)
(2,4) coordinate (C)
(5,2) coordinate (D)
(5,5) coordinate (E)
;
%
\foreach \pt/\labpos in {A/right,D/below left,E/below}{
  \fill (\pt) circle (2pt) node[\labpos=3pt,fill=white]{\pt};
};
\foreach \pt/\labpos in {B/above left,C/above left}{
  \fill (\pt) circle (3pt) node[\labpos=3pt,fill=white]{\pt};
};
\end{tikzpicture}
%\captionsetup{width=0.8\linewidth}
\captionof{figure}{Graphical Illustration of Dataset with an Arbitrary Caption to Highlight the Problem}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

## Third solution

The author, Axel Sommerfeldt, mentions in a comment that there is a new, undocument option to caption, which is `calcwidth`.  Testing this, it works well in your example, at least in the form `calcwidth=0.8\linewidth` as package option. It recalculates the width specification at each use rather than fixing calculated value at the beginning of the document.

If you use `calcwidth=0.8\columnwidth`, you have to be very careful about placement of commands switching numbers of columns.  As your example is a one column layout, I will stick with the simple `\linewidth`.

For illustration I have also added `RaggedRight` to the captions.  This allows some hyphenation, in contrast to `raggedright` which will only break lines at word boundaries.

[image: Sample calc output]

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
tikz,
relsize,
amsmath,
booktabs,
tikz,ragged2e
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\usepackage[
labelfont=sf,
hypcap=false,
format=hang,
margin=1cm,
justification=RaggedRight,
calcwidth=0.8\linewidth
]{caption}

\usetikzlibrary{
calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,
decorations.pathreplacing,
decorations.pathmorphing,
decorations.shapes,
decorations.text,
shapes,
shapes.geometric,
shapes.symbols,
matrix,
patterns,
intersections,
fit}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
>=latex
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[btc]
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Dataset for Something  with an Arbitrary Caption to
Highlight the Problem}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
\toprule
Store & A & B & C & D & E \\
\cmidrule(r{0.125em}){1-1}%
\cmidrule(lr{0.125em}){2-2}%
\cmidrule(lr{0.125em}){3-3}%
\cmidrule(lr{0.125em}){4-4}%
\cmidrule(lr{0.125em}){5-5}%
\cmidrule(l{0.25em}){6-6}%
Input & 0.75 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 5\\
Output & 0.5 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 5\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
%
\draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (6,6);
%
\draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (6.5,0) node[midway,below=8pt]{Output}; %X-Achse
\draw[->,thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6.5) node[above=5pt]{Input}; %Y-Achse
%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](\x cm,-2pt) -- (\x cm,2pt);
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y);
%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw (\x cm, 0 cm) node[anchor=north]{\x} coordinate (x axis);
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,6}  \draw (0 cm, \y cm) node[anchor=east]{\y} coordinate (y axis);
%
\draw
(0,0) coordinate (orig)
(0.75,0.5) coordinate (A)
(1,2) coordinate (B)
(2,4) coordinate (C)
(5,2) coordinate (D)
(5,5) coordinate (E)
;
%
\foreach \pt/\labpos in {A/right,D/below left,E/below}{
  \fill (\pt) circle (2pt) node[\labpos=3pt,fill=white]{\pt};
};
\foreach \pt/\labpos in {B/above left,C/above left}{
  \fill (\pt) circle (3pt) node[\labpos=3pt,fill=white]{\pt};
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Graphical Illustration of Dataset with an Arbitrary Caption to Highlight the Problem}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. A little note: in your first code snippet it should say `\captionsetup{width=0.8\linewidth}`.

Comment: It would be nice if it would autoadjust, but this is currently the best solution

Comment: @henry Thanks.  I was in the process of adding that whilst writing my second solution.

Comment: @daleif The second approach is more in that direction.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, well in that case a more ragged style will be best for the short captions, and we are back at the local `\captionsetup`s

Comment: @daleif Good point. A global RaggedRight might be acceptable in some circumstances.

Comment: Third solution: Don't use `width=0.8\columnwidth` but `calcwidth=0.8\columnwidth` instead. The option `calcwidth` (and `calcmargin`) is available since v3.2 (2011/07/30) of the `caption` package but I didn't find the time to document it so far.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Very good - example added to answer.