# caption package in twocolumn mode: Distinct styles for figure and (wide) figure*

Tags: captions, two-column

I'm using a KOMA-script based twocolumn layout and modifying float captions with the `caption` package. Unfortunately, when redefining the default style, the new options will apply to both column-wide `figure`s and text-wide `figure*`s. This results in captions that do not always have the intended width:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,DIV=16]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[
  justification=RaggedRight,
  width=.9\columnwidth,
]{caption}

\begin{document}


\blindtext
\begin{figure}[htpb]
  \rule{\columnwidth}{2cm}
  \caption{A few words that consume more space than a single line.
    The width of this caption is as intended.
  }
\end{figure}
\blindtext

\clearpage
\begin{figure*}[htpb]
  \rule{\textwidth}{2cm}
  \caption{A few words that consume more space than a single line.
    The width of this caption is too small.
  }
\end{figure*}
\clearpage

\captionsetup{
  justification=RaggedRight,
  width=.9\textwidth,
}

\blindtext
\begin{figure}[htpb]
  \rule{\columnwidth}{2cm}
  \caption{A few words that consume more space than a single line.
    The width of this caption is too large.
  }
\end{figure}
\blindtext

\clearpage
\begin{figure*}[htpb]
  \rule{\textwidth}{2cm}
  \caption{A few words that consume more space than a single line.
    The width of this caption is as intended.
  }
\end{figure*}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

I'm circumventing this for now by manually switching to a separate style defined through `\DeclareCaptionStyle{colfigure}{...}` for column figures using `\captionsetup{style=colfigure}` but I'd prefer not to do this manually. Is there a way to automatise this?

Comment: Usually using `width=...` as global option is a bad idea; it makes more sense when using as (local) option within an environment. Try something like `calcwidth=.9\linewidth` instead.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Can you add an answer too? I did not found option `calcwidth` in the package documentation.

Comment: @esdd Yes, unfortunately the `calcwidth` option is only mentioned in the `CHANGELOG` file. I just took a look, it's available for about 7 years. Shame on me, hopefully an updated documentation will be available at the end of this year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `width=...` option sets the width of the caption to a fixed amount immediately, `calcwidth=...` will evaluate the value if needed, i.e. every time a caption is actually typeset.

So usually using `width=...` as global option is a bad idea; it makes more sense when using as (local) option within a single figure or table.

So try something like `calcwidth=.9\linewidth` instead:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,DIV=16]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[
  justification=RaggedRight,
  calcwidth=.9\linewidth,
]{caption}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{figure}[htpb]
  \rule{\columnwidth}{2cm}
  \caption{A few words that consume more space than a single line.
    The width of this caption is as intended.
  }
\end{figure}
\blindtext

\clearpage
\begin{figure*}[htpb]
  \rule{\textwidth}{2cm}
  \caption{A few words that consume more space than a single line.
    The width of this caption is as intended.
  }
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

`calcwidth=...` was introduced with v3.2 of the `caption` package on 2011/07/30 but is still not part of the documentation. (It's only mentioned in the `CHANGELOG` file.) See also: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/1

A new version v3.4 with a completely revised documentation is planned for the end of this year.

Comment: Thanks @axel, that's precisely what I was looking for (and couldn't find in the docs ;-). I had guessed that this might be related to expansion issues, but didn't really know how to debug it further.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280822/width-in-caption-package-does-not-react-on-linewidth https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128485/how-to-make-a-caption-via-captionof-and-extra-margins-adhere-to-minipage-marg

Answer (score 3):

Here is a suggestion that needs at least KOMA-Script version 3.25 and works only without package `caption`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,DIV=16]{scrartcl}[2018/03/30]% needs version 3.25 or newer
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setcaptionalignment{l}% needs version 3.25
\setcapdynwidth{.9\linewidth}% needs version 3.20

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[htpb]
  \rule{\columnwidth}{2cm}
  \caption{A few words that consume more space than a single line.
    The width of this caption is as intended.
  }
\end{figure}
\blindtext

\clearpage
\begin{figure*}[htpb]
  \rule{\textwidth}{2cm}
  \caption{A few words that consume more space than a single line.
    The width of this caption is too small.
  }
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or with package `ragged2e` and caption alignment `L`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,DIV=16]{scrartcl}[2018/03/30]% needs version 3.25 or newer
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setcaptionalignment{L}% needs version 3.25
\setcapdynwidth{.9\linewidth}% needs version 3.20

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[htpb]
  \rule{\columnwidth}{2cm}
  \caption{A few words that consume more space than a single line.
    The width of this caption is as intended.
  }
\end{figure}
\blindtext

\clearpage
\begin{figure*}[htpb]
  \rule{\textwidth}{2cm}
  \caption{A few words that consume more space than a single line.
    The width of this caption is too small.
  }
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
[ \left{ x\in\mathbf{R} \middle] 0<{|x|}<\frac{5}{3}
\right} ]

\end{document}

Result:

[image]

Comment: But this should work with `caption` package, too, so it seems I have additional work to do. I opened an issue: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/23

Comment: Thank you, that looks like a reasonable fix to the problem. The example was somewhat simplified, my actual caption style uses more options (maybe that could be done in KOMA, too, didn't try).
I prefer the key-value input syntax of the caption package over KOMA-scripts syntax however, thus accepting @AxelSommerfeldt 's answer.